# Query with filtred fields for nested objected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

lets say I've got a document

```
book: {name: "book", 
   "chapters":[{title: "Chapter I", 
   "sections":[{},{}]
   }, {...}
]}
```

I what to get book object with embedded object chapters but each chapter should not contain nested "sections" (but should contain other attributes, like title):

```
book: {name: "Book", 
   "chapters":[{title: "Chapter I"
   }, {...}
]}
```

How should I make a query using **Mongo driver** and **Mongoid** (or **Mongomapper**)?

I tried it with mongoid:

```
books.all[0].chapters.only(:title)[0].sections # it still works, though I expect sections to be nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query

```
 books.all[0].chapters.only(:title)[0].sections
```

picks the books with all its chapter embedded documents on books.all, so there is no meaning to use 'only' after chapters. Your query can work if the chapters as a separate documents and got a has_many relationship instead embeds_many

So you have to use  'only'  like this on books document

```
 books.only('chapters.title').all[0].chapters.sections
```

Comment: Please stop signing all your answers! God, there are loads!

Comment: Each of your 443 answers ends with "Cheers" on a line by itself

Comment: It's just not necessary and they tend to be edited out (though 443 is a bit much for me >.<)

Comment: its just like saying thanks.. thats all dude. there are thousands of posts with thanks and cheers all over.. :( anyways i will stop sign frm now on..

Comment: (I know what it means) Yes, and I remove them where possible! Thanks is implicit; you are writing an answer, not a letter. :)